# HTML Form Behavior with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I ran into an interesting wall today working on a simple form with PHP and HTML and can't think of a quick fix.

I'm using the PHP script I've written when the user presses submit on my HTML page. In order to re-display the page after running the script I simply write

```
include "html_forms.html"
```

at the bottom of the PHP script. Firstly, this seems like a bad design for presenting the page as it needs to be constantly fully re-displayed but I couldn't figure out how to circumvent this problem.

The problem I'm more concerned with here though is that I'm trying to keep the form data from before the user first pressed submit by using PHP. To do this I modify the value of each input like this (within the HTML):

```
value = "<?php echo $website; ?>
```

However, when the webpage is first loaded from the HTML (I'm guessing it can't find the PHP to reference since the Submit button hasn't been clicked yet so) in my entry box on the page the first time it's loaded it prints `<?php echo $website; ?>`. If I load the PHP first it doesn't have that problem but this schism makes me question the overall design that I'm going for and although it might fix the problem in this case it seems like it only works because the simplicity of the webpage.

My main question is how to fix this? I've thought of looking into just emptying the html entries on the first go and other techniques but I'm not sure if this would be the best approach since making special cases especially for the first time the page is clicked seems like bad form.

Thanks in advance for the help guys and this is the first question I've asked on stack-overflow so let me know if there's anyway I could improve my question-asking and don't be too harsh on me!

Comment: have you looked at any php\form tutorials?

Comment: `<?php echo ... ?>` will not work on an `.html` doc. Try changing `html_forms.html` to `html_forms.php`. `.html` will ONLY render html. `.php` will render BOTH html and/or php

Comment: it can work, just not out of the box, not uncommon (i do it) to parses all .html files trough php

Comment: The only question is, why? Why going through the trouble (and high security risk) of using .html as .php?

Comment: Well for an extra added layer of security by obscurity.

Comment: @Dagon you *can* set up your web server to parse HTML files as PHP, but that sounds like a *bad idea*.

Comment: @Kraxor - Actually no, its in the PHP manual for security to setup the ability to save your files as .html or .(whatever) just for obscurity sake. Though it's apparently not a strong security measure, but every layer of security is cool.

Comment: @Charles I don't want to start an off-topic debate here, but [security by design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_by_design) should always be preferred over [security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Renaming your `login.php` to `as.df` and even removing the `X-Powered-By` header (which would otherwise expose PHP anyway) adds very little to security and will give you a headache at some point. Sounds like my 10 years younger self who thought that giving a directory a very long and obscure name on a web server is secure. A lesson learned the hard way.

Comment: Hahahaha, "as.df". I feel you though, I'm still learning.

Comment: i dont see why its a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issue is that your web server does not parse .html files by PHP interpreter. You have two options from here:

1. If you use Apache you may configure .htaccess to have following line:

   AddHandler php5-script .html
2. You may rename your .html file into .php file

However both options are bad design: you should allow user to interact with your PHP script only and use underlying html as template if needed.

Comment: So you're suggesting I figure out a solution within the framework I have set up: HTML as a template and the PHP being called by the HTML?

Comment: Nevermind. I see what you're suggesting. I'll work on modifying it now so that the webpage runs from a .php instead and I'll probably just end up trash binning the .html since it'll become unnecessary. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that you load the page `html_forms.html`, then submit the form to a page like `process_form.php`. Within `process_form.php` you are calling `include 'html_forms.php';` which allows for `value = '<?php echo $website; ?>'` because it's inside a PHP page.

However, when you reload `html_forms.html`, it's back to being just an HTML doc, and so you lose your PHP-ability, and thus, `value = '<?php echo $website; ?>'` is translated to `value = ''` - HTML will completely ignore your PHP.

Short answer: use PHP extensions. Rename `html_forms.html` to `html_forms.php` and you can use all the PHP magic you need.